# Exact implementation of RandomForest in Weka 3.7

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, weka, decision-tree, random-forest

Having reviewed the original Breiman (2001) paper as well as some other board posts, I am slightly confused with the actual procedure used by WEKAs random forest implementation. None of the sources was sufficiently elaborate, many even contradict each other.

***How does it work in detail, which steps are carried out?***

*My understanding till now:*

- For each tree a bootstrap sample of the same size as the training data is created
- Only a random subset of the available features of defined size (parameter can be chosen in WEKA) is considered for each node
- Regarding the base tree learner used I found a 2006 post stating is was a modified REPTree.
- Tree is fully grown and not pruned.
- Majority vote is applied (in case of accuracy as performance metric)

*My questions:*

- Is the bootstrap sampling actually used?
- Is REPTree still in use or has the algorithm been changed since then?

Clarifying these issues would help me a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your questions

1. Bagging (bootstrap aggregation) is indeed used. You can view that in the code on line [529](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/weka-dev/3.7.5/weka/classifiers/trees/RandomForest.java#529)
2. It appears that RandomTree is used, as seen on line [530](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/weka-dev/3.7.5/weka/classifiers/trees/RandomForest.java#529)

This information is from Weka 3.7.5, I believe this is correct all the way back to version 3.6.8, but I have not checked the source code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, first question solved. It indeed uses the RandomTree but the question remaining would be on which one RT is based - CART or REPTree presumably but not for sure.

Comment: I'm not sure your familiarity with Java, but you could compare the two buildTree() methods: [RandomTree](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/weka-dev/3.7.5/weka/classifiers/trees/RandomTree.java#991), [RepTree](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/weka-dev/3.7.5/weka/classifiers/trees/REPTree.java#503).  To me they look very similar, but I can't find a recent source saying that they are the same.

Comment: Thanks Ill take a look. Its said to be a slightly modified version of the REPTree. Can't see anything on the mobile screen though Ill check it out at home. Thanks

Comment: @Walter "Yes it is true that WEKA's RandomForest is not based on CART, but it is also not based on J48,  rather a variant of REPTree modified to be include the desired randomness, and not pruned" http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/How-does-Random-Forest-work-in-weka-td4863.html