# Does the weka RandomForest use bootstrap to take trainset

Tags: weka, random-forest

i use weka explorer,it has the train/test split percentage item.It take dataset into trainset and testset in given percentage.i dont know whether it will have repeated instance in trainset in weka RF.and whether the repeated will effect the result.
the RandomForest i know use bootstrap and the trainset have repeated instance and have same size with dataset.

Answer (score 0):

> whether it will have repeated instance in trainset in weka RF

yes, it makes bootstrap sample, so there will be repeated instances, have a look at the answer here: [Exact implementation of RandomForest in Weka 3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19137243/exact-implementation-of-randomforest-in-weka-3-7)

> and whether the repeated will effect the result

Well, it is the nature of Random Forest, it's how it works. But remember it just learns on repeated instance, the test set used for evaluation is left untouched.